# A vector is created from different vectors and i want to find starting and ending positions of these vectors in the vector created from them

Tags: r, vector, indexing

These vectors will always be in increasing order such as 1 ..2 ... 3 ..4. They cannot decrease. Let's say I have three vectors as an example.

```
v1 <- c(1,3)
v2 <- c(2)
v3 <- c(1,3,4)
```

And I have a vector that was created from these vectors:

```
vsum <- c(v2, v1, v3)
```

Now i want to create a code which can find the position where each vector (v1,v2,v3) **starts**  and **ends** in vsum. In this case, the starting position would look like

```
start <- c(1,2,4)
```

because if I run vsum these are the starting positions of each vector.

**2** **1** 3 **1** 3 4

the ending position would look like

```
end <- c(1,3,6)
```

because these are ending positions

**2** 1 **3** 1 3 **4**

Comment: The problem is that there is no guaranteed unique solution for this. What if two of the vectors were the same? Or what if the two vectors were `c(1, 2)` and `c(1, 2, 1, 2)`? Or is that somehow not possible? Also, do the vectors contain only integers, or might they contain floating point numbers where testing for equality might be more difficult?

Comment: Okay my fault. I edited my post too. The vectors will always be in increasing order. They cannot decrease . c(1, 2, 1, 2) is not possible. they can contain integers or decimals too. But i think for now an example with integers will be suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your vectors in a list and use `lengths` with `cumsum`:

```r
v1 <- c(1,3)
v2 <- c(2)
v3 <- c(1,3,4)
l = lengths(list(v2, v1, v3))
# [1] 1 2 3

start = cumsum(l) - l + 1
# [1] 1 2 4

end = cumsum(l)
# [1] 1 3 6
```